# I need help in speeding up the execution's time of my stored proc

Tags: sql-server

I wanna ask some little question.How can i speed up the perfomance of the next stored proc.First,a need to say that there are 30 000 000 rows in the next table:

```
CREATE TABLE tblT
  ( 
   [RowID] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1)
                 NOT NULL
  ,[CheckDateID] int NOT NULL
  ,[SSN] varchar(10)
  ,[CheckDate] datetime
  ,[val] money
    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblT]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [CheckDateID] ASC, [RowID] ASC )
  )
```

And here we are,this is a SP and i need some reasonable advices on how i'll be able to modify this proc.Critical here is a Time of proc's execution...

```
DECLARE @RowMin [int]
 ,@RowMax [int]
 ,@Portion [int]
 ,@CurMin [int]
 ,@CurMax [int]
 ,@strMessage varchar(100)


SET @RowMin = ( SELECT min (RowID) FROM tblT )
SET @RowMax = ( SELECT max (RowID) FROM tblT )
SET @Portion = 350000
SET @CurMin = @RowMin
SET @CurMax = @CurMin + @Portion

WHILE @CurMax <> @CurMin
BEGIN

    Update A
    set val = val*8,3, --???
    from tblT  A 
    where A.RowID Between  @CurMin and @CurMax

    SET @CurMin = @CurMax
    SET @CurMax = case WHEN ( @CurMax + @Portion ) < @RowMax
                    THEN @CurMax + @Portion
                    ELSE @RowMax
                  END

END
```

Comment: Please select both the table code AND the stored procedure code and click the "1010" button.

Comment: How long does it take with the current procedure?

Comment: I am sure there must be a good reason why you not just simply use a 

UPDATE tblIT set val = val*8,3;

please tell us.

Comment: Did my best with formatting, you fix the update statement.

Comment: Do note that code you posted does not parse, so no point in talking about optimization until it's fixed.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could describe your overall goal with this SP. One this is to optimize it as it is, a better thing is to look at what you want to achieve and analyze the whole problem.

Comment: Like Doc Brown said: it's doing "UPDATE tblIT SET val = val*8.3"

Answer (score 3):

Some thoughts:

- Is there an index on RowID?
- Why not do

  **SELECT @RowMin=min(RowID),@RowMax=max(RowId) FROM tbLT**

instead of two separate queries

- Why not simply

  **update tbLT SET val=val*8.3 WHERE rowID BETWEEN @CurMin and @CurMax**
- And the biggest question, why are you chunking the update statement?   It
  seems to me you are trying to do

**update tbLT SET val=val*8.3**

Do you need to break the update statement into smaller pieces for contention reason?   What is the recovery model on this database, you could be getting a performance hit from SQL logging this update operation...

Answer (score 1):

Besides what Sparky said - why did you choose to put the PK on `(CheckDateId,RowID)` ?? Any particular reason?

By doing this, you basically made this index unusable for queries (like your `UPDATE` statement) which reference `RowID` alone --> you'll end up having full table scans instead.

Three options:

1. Put your PK on `(RowID)` alone
2. Change your PK to be on `(RowID, CheckDateID)` - yes, order **does** matter in this case!
3. Add a new non-clustered index on `(RowID)` alone

All three options are designed to speed up the range query on the `RowID` that you have in your `UPDATE` statement.

Be forewarned, however - tweaking your database structure to speed this one query up could potentially have side-effects on the rest of your system and your other queries, and you could potentially slow those down. Tweaking just a single query / stored proc in isolation is always a very dangerous operation - you could wreck a lot of havoc on the rest of the system.